# Can ajaxProgressiveLoad work with Overriding the Request Promise in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

It did work with `pagination: "remote"`, but **some kind of reason that we have to use customize ajax function in .net ** but not `ajaxURL` option.

Is that a feature request? Thanks for help in advance.

---

Here are the following code:

- pagination: "remote" with customize ajax(It works)

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function queryRealm(url, config, params) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'data.php',
                success: function(data){
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                },
                error: function(error){
                    reject(error);
                }
            })
        });
    }

    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        ajaxRequestFunc: queryRealm,
        pagination: 'remote',
        columns: [{
                title: "id",
                field: "id",
            },
            {
                title: "Name",
                field: "name",
                width: 200
            }
        ],
        height: "292px",
    });
```

- ajaxProgressiveLoad: "scroll" with customize ajax(It doesn't work)

just change `pagination: 'remote',`  to `ajaxProgressiveLoad: "scroll"`

And data.php is following:

```
$data = [
    ["id"=>1, "name"=>"Billy Bob============"],
    ["id"=>2, "name"=>"Mary May"],
    ["id"=>3, "name"=>"Christine Lobowski"],
    ["id"=>4, "name"=>"Brendon Philips"],
    ["id"=>5, "name"=>"Margret Marmajuke"],
    ["id"=>6, "name"=>"Christine Lobowski"],
    ["id"=>7, "name"=>"Brendon Philips"],`enter code here`
    ["id"=>8, "name"=>"Margret Marmajuke"],
    ["id"=>9, "name"=>"Margret Marmajuke"],
];

echo(json_encode(["last_page"=>10, "data"=>$data]));
```

---

updated an image
[enable ajaxUrl option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cePgg.png)

Comment: You request is a bit vauge im afraid. i would recommend including a copy of your table constructor object so we can better understand how your table is setup.

Comment: @OliFolkerd Hi Oil, just edit the question yet, thanks for remind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work as long as your are formatting your returned data in the paginated form that Tabulator is expecting:

```
{
    "last_page":15, //the total number of available pages (this value must be greater than 0)
    "data":[ // an array of row data objects
        {"id":1, "name":"bob", "age":"23"} //example row data object
    ]
}
```

and you are correctly passing the ***page*** parameter back to your server.

Though looking at the ajaxRequestFunc it is not doing anything that the built in ajax system dosnt already do (especially since its improvements in v4.1) so im not sure why it is needed in the first place.

You will need to make sure the ***ajaxURL*** option has a value in order for your custom loader to be called

Comment: Hi Oli, I found if I enable ajaxUrl with not an empty string, it works. but I don't know  is that a good practice in Tabulator. I have updated my question for an image.

Comment: Side note I found the following config is also 4 times request to data.php as the picture.  
  
`ajaxRequestFunc: queryRealm`  
`ajaxURL: "data.php", //ajax`  
`ajaxProgressiveLoad: "scroll",`

Comment: yes you will need to have an ajax url even if it isnt used in your loader function, because that is what triggers tabulator to make the call. i have updated my answer